# How do I unlock areas in Find Mii 2?

Tags: streetpass-quest-find-mii-2

I was playing through the secret quest in Find Mii 2 and tried to go to the Shrine of Judgement, but I got a message saying it was locked, and to try again later.

How later? You can't exactly go back in this game, only forward to the next area, so if I choose a different path, I will have to wait until my next playthrough.

What do I need to do to unlock these paths?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These locatons unlock in future playthroughs. Unfortunately when you finished the game (which I am assuming you did) and you selected the secret mission you made yourself ineligible on this playthrough to unlock the doors. See [this](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/locked-door-in-find-mii-ii.250060296/) IGN thread. It is generally suggested to play through the game multiple times unitl you have visited all of the paths and THEN tackle the secret quests.

So basically if you want these paths to unlock you can't take on the secret quests you need to just select a new playthrough.

Answer (score 2):

You will get the key after completing your second playthrough of the first part, and then you will have to play through it a third time to finally clear all the rooms. I had played the secret quest first so I don't know how that matters. My playthrough was: first part x1, secret part x1, first part x2, first part x3 so far. I don't know if it is required for you to have all other areas on the map cleared first.

Answer (score 1):

When I completed a playthrough, I got one of the locked paths unlocked.